ranking formula start from negative number
How to make a ranking formula but starting from negative numbers and preventing double rankings



SCORE
RANK




-50
1


-25
2


-20
3


-10
5


-20
4


-10
6


-1
7


0
8


3
10


1
9



This is the link.
I tried the formula but it didn't work as I expected =RANK(A2,$A$2:$A)

So sorry, i delete the tag


You may try:
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,rank(Σ,A:A,1)+let(Λ,countif(A2:Σ,Σ),if(Λ>1,Λ-1,)))))



Thanks - I'll delete my comment.

Can you explain what for sigma and lambda symbol in that formula?

I used those symbols as per my convenience. You can totally change them as per how you want to name the identifier. Look into LAMBDA formula documentation for a bit more clarity

Thank you for your explanation
